# pynput.mouse.Listener specific suppress (Python)

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, pynput

I have this code that listens to mouse events and uses `suppress = True` to  prevent the
events from being passed to the rest of the system. (Locking the mouse in position and blocking all inputs).

```
def on_move(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(button, pressed

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print(dx, dy)

with pynput.mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem is that I only want to suppress the input of the mouse (`on_click`, `on_scroll`) and not the movement (`on_move`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at "How do I suppress specific events only?" section in:
https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

The provided solutions are for Windows and MacOS, but not for Linux.